# AWS DynamoDB - Dynamically setting DynamoDBTable in object persistence model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.0 project using AWSDynamodDb (you can ignore dynamo db here as question is not regarding dynamodDB)

I have the following entity class as:

```
[DynamoDBTable("TableName")]
public class MyData
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string Id{ get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

What I want is the "TableName" - **the value passed into the attribute** - to be populated from my appSettings.json file.

```
 {
    "TableName": "NewTable" 
 }
```

Would it be possible to get this value durring runtime by looking at the key from appSettings file?

--Updated--

I am calling the "MyData" class from my controller as below:

```
  var response = await context.ScanAsync<MyData>(conditions).GetRemainingAsync();
```

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes I am already using configurations in my application. In Startup as:    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration). And then in my class which requires the key as: IConfiguration _configuration; _configuration["UserId"]. But how can I get it over this class attribute?

Comment: @gunr2171 should be fine, but what edits are you talking about. I have updated my code, please check.

Comment: Oh wait, you're talking about trying to change the value of the `[DynamoDBTable]` attribute using the configuration file?

Comment: @gunr2171 yeah, I just realized that is what he is trying to do, I'm looking to see if there is anything like the `ConfigurationPropertyAttribute` decoration that was available in the .NetFramework

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I should have made it more clear while posting. In MVC controller we could create custom filter/attribute so I was looking something around those lines. The above class is being called in my MVC controller of an API.  I just dint wanted to hardcode the attribute values and wanted to see if there is an option to get these from the appSettings.json.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for anyone else who come across I was able to resolve this as below:

Remove the table name from the model.

And then use the below code to set the table name dynamically

```
    public static DynamoDBOperationConfig GetDynamoDbOperationConfig(string dynamoDbTable)
    {
        DynamoDBOperationConfig config = new DynamoDBOperationConfig() { OverrideTableName = dynamoDbTable };
        return config;
    }
```

We can call this function whenever we are calling any operation against dynamo db like scan, save, delete etc.

Comment: Hi aman i tried  Your Code. But  the  table is not dynamically loading.  I have assumed  the code from start GetDynamoDbOperationConfig("MyData"); It did not shows the error. But the table is not inserted. When i give   [DynamoDBTable("MyData")]   the datas are storing  in DynamoDB.   I have try to use this code by this way  [DynamoDBTable( H ighLevelTableExample.GetDynamoDbOperationConfig(S_tablefieldset))] // s_tablefield set is a string variable. So  How do you call the variable dynamically. if you share your code it would helpful for many peoples.